# JNDI context initialization fails in Tomcat when connecting via JMX

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi, jmx, jconsole

I have a webapp deployed in Tomcat 7.0.8. Recently I started implementing MBeans to be able to monitor a few actions, which normally are invoked from a quartz scheduler. I connect to Tomcat's MBean server using JConsole and invoke a method, which tries to connect to a database via JNDI.

When execution reaches
`Context initContext = new InitialContext();` the following exception is thrown:

> javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory]

When the method is called from the regular servlet (a JAX-WS webservice), there are no problems with the class loading. It seems class loading works differently when JMX is involved, but I can't figure out how... Could it have something to do with `RMI class loader disabled`, which JConsole tells me?

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround for this sort of issue: retrieve the classloader for the class containing your `Context initContext = new InitialContext();` code, and set it to be the current classloader for the thread.

```
ClassLoader origLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
Object obj = ctx.lookup("java:global/some/path");
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(origLoader);
```

This has worked for me for problems with classloading when making method calls from a JMX console.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's actually a little more complex then that; you're used to the [Web Container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Servlet_containers) - but [JMX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JMX) MBeans run in a different container (with a seperate life-cycle). That is the [MBeanServer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServer.html).

[image: The MBeanServer]

Comment: OK, does that mean that I cannot reach any JNDI resources defined in web.xml / server.xml? Is there any other way to define resources, so that I, without changing the implementing code, can reach a JNDI datasource?

Comment: Use an external [Registry Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jndi/jndi-rmi.html).

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the context was available during startup, so I made a `ServletContextListener` save the datasource (looked up from the context) in a static variable. When my application requests a database connection, it is retrieved from the stored datasource.